# multiple Python installation pip not work

Tags: python, pip

I have Centos and default version of python which is installed is python 2.7
For my project I want python 3.4.

I've downloaded python 3.4 source code and build and installed it first time with altinstall and 
second time with install (overwriting default python)
but nothing changes
and every time I want to install a new module with pip install it installed module for python 2.7
and I've seen to use pip for new version I should use command python3.4 -m pip install 
but it says: no module named pip
it seems that pip is not installed with this new python 3.4

What should I do?

Didn't found any right solution anywhere

Comment: Did you try pip3 install ?

Comment: I don't have experience with CentOS but in Debian/Ubuntu you have to use `update-alternatives` so that the default python is 3.4

Comment: @Timo yes, but just works in python 2.7 not in 3.4

Comment: You change your `pip` commands to `pip3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ChrisWarrick , @MattiLyra
Thanks for replying and answering my questions and giving me information.

I've added epel reposity:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

and after that installed pip3.4 for python 3.4:

```
sudo yum install python34-setuptools

sudo easy_install-3.4 pip
```

after that checked installed versions with:

```
pip3.4 list
```

but when importing modules in python 
it said no module name

I checked installed modules informations with

```
pip show (modulename)
```

and got the path of module name

and again entered into python with:

```
python3.4
```

and import a standard module of python and check the path of file:

```
import os
os.__file__
```

and and got the default modules path and copy installed modules binaries to the default path:

for example:

```
 cp -r osa /usr/local/lib/python3.4/
 cp _mssql.cpython-34m.so /usr/local/lib/python3.4/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis is exactly correct, `pip` is not installed when you install `python` from sources, it is a separate package that needs to be installed separately. Although the binaries for `2.7.9 >=` and `3.4 >=` contain `pip`. You can check which `pip` is being called with `pip -V`

You can install `pip` using the `get-pip.py` script from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py *but* you have to make sure you're calling that with the intended python version, so before installing make sure `python --version` is the one you're intending to use.

To make your own life easier I recommend you use `miniconda` to manage the python environments, `miniconda` will actually install `pip` when you create a new environment.

https://conda.io/miniconda.html

alternatively you can use `virtualenv` but I find `conda` easier to manage.

Comment: Is there any sultion except miniconda? I want to do it manually if it will be in server which dont want to use lots of internet bandwidth there

Comment: after calling python3.4 get-pip.py get error : can not decompress data; zlib not avaiable. it seems zlib not installed for python 3.4. :(((((

Comment: `zlib` is part of the python standard library so you must be missing `zlib` on the CentOS box itself, use the package manager for the OS to install it https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/zlib.html

Comment: when I enter yum install zlib my os has it. but the error occurs again after python3.4 get-pip.py :   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

Comment: @Hamed_gibago You need to recompile your Python with zlib support (there is a ./configure switch) and you need the appropriate `-devel` packages for your system. Also, `pip` should be installed automatically by modern Pythons (why 3.4 and not 3.6?)

Comment: will you explain more about -devel ? I should change somethind in ./configure? I use python 3.4 because of support of pymssql and import _mssql module in my source. because I heared that latest version for _mssql for python is 3.4, maybe its for time I was developing in python in windows. maybe it is supported in 3.6 linux

Comment: @ChrisWarrick will you answer?

Comment: @Hamed_gibago (1) At least `zlib-devel` is needed, there might be others. Look into `yum-builddep`. (2) No need to change anything in the file, but there *might* be configure switches you need to change.  https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/unix.html (3) They support 3.5 right now, and it’s very likely it will just work with 3.6 if you compile it for that version. (4) note that CentOS provides Python 3.4 in [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and you should just use that if you can.